# SQL join query returns each result three times

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables, tx and earliest. I’m trying to join them based on "UserId" and "AcceptorCode", and only return the records where "CreatedOn" in tx is greater than or equal to "EarliestPayDate" in earliest.

```sql
WITH tx AS
(
    SELECT 
        "AcceptorCode", 
        "UserId", 
        "CreatedOn",
        "Amount",
        "WithdrawType",
        "DepositType",
        "Balance"
    FROM 
        "public"."Transactions"
    WHERE 
       -- "AcceptorCode" IS NOT NULL AND 
       -- "AcceptorCode" != ''
    "CreatedOn" BETWEEN {{START_DATE}} AND {{END_DATE}}
), 
earliest AS
(
    SELECT 
        "AcceptorCode", 
        "UserId", 
        MIN(CAST("CreatedOn" AS date)) AS "EarliestPayDate"
    FROM 
        tx
    WHERE 
        "AcceptorCode" IN ('000000014578478', '000000900030378', '000000005227597')
    GROUP BY 
        "AcceptorCode", 
        "UserId"
), 
wages AS 
(
    SELECT 
        e."UserId", t.*
    FROM 
        tx t
    JOIN 
        earliest e ON t."UserId" = e."UserId" AND (t."AcceptorCode" IS NULL OR t."AcceptorCode" = '')
    WHERE 
        t."CreatedOn" >= e."EarliestPayDate"
    ORDER BY 
        e."UserId" DESC   
)
SELECT *
FROM wages
```

The problem is that each result is returned three times.

[image]

How can I modify my query to return each result only once?

---

**EDIT**:

The use of `SELECT DISTINCT "UserId"` can address the issue with the query above. However, when I use aggregations and `GROUP BY`, it sums the amounts three times.

```
WITH tx AS
(
    ...
), 
earliest AS
(
    ...
), 
wages AS 
(
    SELECT 
        e."UserId", 
        SUM(CASE WHEN t."WithdrawType" IN (2, 3) THEN t."Amount" ELSE 0 END) AS "TotalWithdrawalWage",
        SUM(CASE WHEN t."DepositType" = 4 THEN t."Amount" ELSE 0 END) AS "TotalDepositWage"
    FROM 
        tx t
    JOIN 
        earliest e ON t."UserId" = e."UserId"
    WHERE 
        t."CreatedOn" >= e."EarliestPayDate"
    GROUP BY 
        e."UserId"
    ORDER BY 
        e."UserId" DESC   
)
SELECT *, "TotalWithdrawalWage" - "TotalDepositWage" AS "Difference"
FROM wages
WHERE "TotalWithdrawalWage" > 0 OR "TotalDepositWage" > 0
ORDER BY "UserId" DESC
```

[image]

Comment: This means the JOIN conditions are not sufficiently specific, allowing a row in the first table to match multiple rows in the additional table. If you need it to only match one, you need to write the JOIN condition to be more precise. But from what I can see, this looks like a situation where you'll be better off switching from using a `group by` strategy to a `row_number()` strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting 3 copies of each user is because in your `earliest AS(...),` definition, you are grouping by `AcceptorCode + UserId`.  So you will be the smallest `CreatedOn` for each `AcceptorCode + UserId` combination.  When this is passed to the surrounding `SELECT` and joined with `tx` again, using `t."UserId" = e."UserId"`, each `t."UserId"` will match each of the 3 `e."UserId"` values, since there is no join condition on `e."AcceptorCode"`.  I don't know what you're trying to achieve, since you are looking for `t."AcceptorCode" IS NULL OR t."AcceptorCode" = ''` -- there does not seem to be a clear intention to join `t` and `e` datasets

If you are simply trying to get the `EarliestPayDate` per-user, then you can change the `earliest AS(...)` definition to read:

```
earliest AS(
    SELECT 
        "UserId", 
        MIN(CAST("CreatedOn" AS date)) AS "EarliestPayDate"
    FROM 
        tx
    WHERE 
    "AcceptorCode" IN (
    '000000014578478','000000900030378','000000005227597' )
    GROUP BY 
        "UserId"
),
```

and also put `AND (t."AcceptorCode" IS NULL OR t."AcceptorCode" = '')` after `WHERE`

Comment: Excellent. Merci for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In subquery `earliest` you have 3 records for every `userId` - one for each of `AcceptorCode`s mentioned in the filter, since you are grouping by both of these fields.

I suppose you need to group by `userId` only:

```sql
earliest AS(
    SELECT 
        "UserId", 
        MIN(CAST("CreatedOn" AS date)) AS "EarliestPayDate"
    FROM 
        tx
    WHERE 
    "AcceptorCode" IN (
    '000000014578478','000000900030378','000000005227597' )
    GROUP BY 
        "UserId"
)
```